# Need help for using JSON data in windows app

Tags: json, windows

Suppose this is my JSON data received through API...

var client = new HttpClient();

```
        var uri = new Uri("blabla.com");
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

[

{

"id": "1",

```
    "title": "Test_rom",
    "subtitle": "",
    "icon": "http://lpl.info/Admin/upload/cat.1.png"
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Jewelry",
    "subtitle": "",
    "icon": "http://lpl.info/Admin/upload/cat.2.png"
},

{
    "id": "3",
    "title": "Jackets",
    "subtitle": "All sizes available",
    "icon": "http://lpl.info/Admin/upload/cat.3.png"
}
```

]
after this I created a class RootObject... 
public class RootObject
 {

public string id { get; set; }

```
public string title { get; set; }
public string subtitle { get; set; }
public string icon { get; set; }
```

}

NoW i only want to show values of "title" keys...(using C#)

RootObject TotalList = new RootObject();

string hub = " ";

foreach (var d in TotalList.title)

{hub = hub + " " + d.ToString(); }

ResultsText.Text=hub;

but this is giving error..plz help

Comment: First please read again, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Second, I asked before, are you using a debugger?

Comment: Third, post the exact error

Comment: yes,,i use debugger... btw i solved this  :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of await you should use.  Await will continue processing without waiting for the response so you'd see null.

```
var response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
```

You should not loop through your class object field. This is wrong

```
foreach (var d in TotalList.title)

{hub = hub + " " + d.ToString(); }
```

If the TotalList is populated (you should be able to see that in a debugger) you can access the value of title using

```
TotalList.title
```

I hope this helps you some, don't give up.

Comment: i had solved this problem...yes,you are right. thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using this format....

private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

```
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var uri = new Uri("http://blabla.com");
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        RootObject TotalList = new RootObject();

           MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
          DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<RootObject>));
          List <RootObject> resu =(List<RootObject>)ser.ReadObject(ms);
```

string hub = " ";

foreach (RootObject d in resu)

{ hub = hub + " " + d.title.ToString(); }

ResultsText.Text = hub;